# How to prevent duplicate content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have a website build for two groups both groups are working on a different domain but this domain points to the same website en show partly the same and partly different content. Is this going to be seen as duplicate content?

**My set-up:**

One Drupal (CMS) Installation.
I have two urls group1.com and group2.com when group1.com the end up on a homepage showing different information then going to group1.com. This is all fine. But on both sites there are articles.

*group 1 has access to:*

- group1.com/article-001
- group1.com/article-002
- group1.com/article-005
- group1.com/article-006
- group1.com/article-007
- group1.com/article-009

*group 2 has access to:*

- group2.com/article-001
- group2.com/article-002
- group2.com/article-003
- group2.com/article-004
- group2.com/article-005
- group2.com/article-007
- group2.com/article-008

So article-001, article-002, article-005 and article-007 are the same, and because of the different domain I think the are seen as duplicates. How to prevent negative impact because of this?

Is this as simple as adding a canonical url saying group1.com or group2.com is the original?

Comment: ***Is this as simple as adding a canonical url saying group1.com or group2.com is the original?*** Yes. Sorta. Unless you want both in search. If that is the case, you have to have unique content on each site to properly enable search users to find the right site themselves. The canonical tags go on the article pages on both domains and point to the preferred version. The preferred pages could be on one domain or divided across both which I am not sure I would recommend without understanding your sites better. Cheers!!